VBA - Nested loop to index j items in i groups
I have groups (from 1, 2 ... to i), each group contains j items.
I want to index each items (from 1,2,3,4 ... all the way to the end).
Like:



i
j
index




1
1
1


1
2
2


1
3
3


2
1
4


2
2
5


3
1
6


3
2
7


3
3
8


3
4
9



I think i can do that with a nested for loops (For i = 1 to ... For j = 1 to ...), but it turns out formulating the relationship between index of each items with (i,j) seems difficult.
Can anyone help?
I tried different formulas:
index  = j + (i-1) * j
index = j + i*(j-1)

...
Some sort of, but they failed.

Loop the items and count and, for each item, set your index to the current count.

Be careful: index might be a reserved word in VBA, e.g. Index() function in Excel

What do you mean by "I want to index each items"? I suppose that what you show in your picture on the "Index" column is not what you need. Am I wrong? If not, it would be good to place there the exact output you need... Do you need the output from "j" column and you show "Index" only to confuse us...?

Start with index at 1 increment it for each line of your data and create an index array for i_ibase[] each time the value "i" in your data changes (i_base[1]=1 etc). Then you know where to find the first occurrence of a specific value of "i" in your data.  General index = i_base[i]+j  BTW your statement of the problem is confusing j is actually j[i] and varies with i so that any simple formula is doomed to  fail (unless you determine max(j) first and are prepared to waste a lot of space.

Do you mean =ROW()-1 in cell C2 to copy down, or =SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A11)) which will spill down? Also, in VBA you don't need to loop. You can use drg.Value = ws.Exalutae("ROW(1:" & srg.Rows.Count & ")") where srg is the range in column A or B and drg is the same range in column C. Please describe your requirement more accurately and add more code.

Please, try the next version. It uses a Scriptinig Dictionary, loading the items as keys and the indexes as items.
It is able to do the job even if the items are not alphabetically sorted! I mean, it can be 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2 and so on, instead of 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 and so on...
It returns in a different range, being very fast, even for huge ranges. If all the time the items are sorted, you can use an array (arrFin) of only one column...
Sub IndexItems()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster procerssing
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necesssary dictionary
  'iterate between the array rows and load the necessary data
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(1)
    Else
        arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)) 'extract the item array
        ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'redim it with an element
        arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arrIt(UBound(arrIt) - 1) + 1 'Place as the last element the previous
                                                            'one plus a unit
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the array
    End If
  Next i
  
  'Process the dictionary data and place them in the final array
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2) ' Make place for the necessary data:
  Dim countEl As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    countEl = UBound(dict.Items()(i)) + 1 'the number of dictionary item array elements
                                          '(+ 1 because it is a1D array)
    For j = 1 To countEl
        k = k + 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.keys()(i): arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(j - 1)
    Next j
  Next i
  
  'drop the array content, at once:
  ws.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub

And the simple way, working only with sorted items:
Sub SimpleIndexItems()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, iCount As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster procerssing
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = arr(i - 1, 1) Then
        iCount = iCount + 1       'increment the count variable
        arrFin(i - 1, 1) = iCount 'place it in the arrFin if identic with the above value
        If i = UBound(arr) Then arrFin(i, 1) = iCount + 1 'only for the last array element...
    Else
        arrFin(i - 1, 1) = iCount + 1: iCount = 0 'place the count and reset the variable
    End If
  Next i
  
  'drop the array content, at once:
  ws.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub

